# Testing a live GCM push notification with only one selected device

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I developed an app, and its now live on the google play store, the app has a GCM push notification, but i made an adjustment in the notification service and now I want to test the url that triggers the notification, but the issue is how do I test the notification such that it sends the notification only to my device. what triggers the notification is a URL that is called.Please i need a detailed explanation on how to do this. Thank you

Comment: you can send tht notification to the particular GCM_REGISTRATION_ID from server side you need to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM push is sent to users according to their gcm Ids you want to send only to one device just push the GCM message for only the gcm id of that device and the message will be received by only that device

Comment: from your server code from where you are sending the push to devices

Comment: Thank you  Pramod this is the server code, where do i input the  gcm id of that device   <?php
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];
     
    include_once './GCM.php';
     
    $gcm = new GCM();
 
    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);
 
    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
 
    echo $result;
}
?>

Comment: i do not know PHP i am an android guy but from your code i guess in send_notification only pass the registration id of the device to which you want to send the notification not all the ids

Comment: thanks Pramod, i will try this i get back to you. i will definitely accept your answer if this works